# GroovyCastException when calling java.util.zip.ZipFile.getInputStream()

Tags: java, groovy, casting, inputstream

I am trying to read a file from a jar archive, and return it as an java.io.InputStream.

Here is the method where I am trying to accomplish this:

```
InputStream getExportInfo(path) {
  def zipFile = new java.util.zip.ZipFile(new File(path))

  zipFile.entries().each { entry ->
    def name = entry.name
    if (!entry.directory && name == "ExportInfo") {
      java.io.InputStream is = zipFile.getInputStream(entry)
      return is
    }
  }
}
```

However I am getting this error from console:

> org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.typehandling.GroovyCastException: Cannot cast object 'java.util.zip.ZipFile$ZipEntryIterator@49defb82' with class 'java.util.zip.ZipFile$ZipEntryIterator' to class 'java.io.InputStream'

It looks like the .getInputStream(entry) doesn't return a 'java.io.InputStream', but it should according to the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/zip/ZipFile.html)

Where does this 'cast' even come from ?

Comment: Is that the entire error message? Which line causes the error?

Comment: And how do you call this method?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice it also prints a stack trace which ends up at the `zipFile.entries().each { entry -> ` line. I am calling this method like this: `def exportInfo = jarHandler.getExportInfo(jarPath)`

Comment: You should edit your question to show the fill stack trace

Comment: The problem is with the closure, not the getInputStream() call.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are returning from the closure, which brings the cast exeption up when your call the method.

The easy fix would be to change the groovy iteration to plain `for` loop:

```
InputStream getExportInfo(path) {
  def zipFile = new java.util.zip.ZipFile(new File(path))

  for( ZipEntry entry in zipFile.entries() ){
    def name = entry.name
    if (!entry.directory && name == "ExportInfo") {
      return zipFile.getInputStream(entry)
    }
  }
}
```

then it would break the loop and return your inputStream instance.